# jQuery and Vimeo Froogaloop2 API onPlayProgress

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I want when user rewinds the video, to change text on the side of the vide, but now I want to start first to setup this code.I fount this code on the internet and I really don't know why this code does not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> </title>

</head>
<body>

<iframe id="player1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?api=1&player_id=player1" width="630" height="354" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div>
  <button>Play</button>
  <button>Pause</button>
  <p>Status: <span class="status">&hellip;</span></p>
</div>


   <script src="https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
   <script> $(function() {
    var iframe = $('#player1')[0];
    var player = $f(iframe);
    var status = $('.status');

    // When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
    player.addEvent('ready', function() {
        status.text('ready');

        player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
        player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
        player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
    });

    // Call the API when a button is pressed
    $('button').bind('click', function() {
        player.api($(this).text().toLowerCase());
    });

    function onPause() {
        status.text('paused');
    }

    function onFinish() {
        status.text('finished');
    }

    function onPlayProgress(data) {
        status.text(data.seconds + 's played');
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So if anyone have idea how to fix this, pleas help!

Answer (score 0):

The code above pretty much set handlers for events happening inside the Vimeo video. The event that you need to use is 'seekTo'. So you would add an event just like the other ones, and if the current playtime is less than what the seekTo playtime, we know we have detected a rewind.

And inside that rewind logic, we can manipulate our text on the side.